Derailleur clunks into 7
I have a Shimano 7speed. The shifter goes full range, but when putting it into 7, the derailleur clunks down in a stepwise fashion, especially with increased power applied.

On your bike, is 7 the cog with the most teeth, or the least ?

So you're saying that a single step from 6 to 7 clicks several times before it engages properly?

If shifting while applying power on pedals then yes it will clung loudly specially if going uphill and going down into a lower gear at the same time .  Could you please re- edit your question so it's a bit clearer what the problem is?  If it's just noisy please rephrase.  Is your shifter index? Most shifter will change one gear at a time, which is the right way to change gears but if you have a friction none index then yeah going up more than one gear at a time would definitely be noisy and hard on the chain.
